# xlsm file error upon sending through email

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am a newbie vba coder here.

I have created an .xlsm with userform. Everything works fine in my computer, but when I send the file over via email, the recipient will encounter the following issues when opening the file:

1. I added an event handler on Workbook_Open to automatically open the userform. When the recipient open the file, it will receive this error and **Debug** button returns to this line:

[image]
[image]

2. When Submit button of the Userform is clicked, the data is supposed to be transferred to 'ThisWorkbook' but instead it creates a new file (i guess the previous version) and paste the data there.

Can anyone help me to figure out what went wrong with my file? Thank you.

Below is my code:

Inside Workbook Event Handler:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

RunForm

End Sub
```

Module1:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub PopulateComboBox()

Dim PaymentTerms() As String, PaymentFreq() As String, PaymentTermsAlt() As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer, o As Integer

j = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Populate").Columns("A:A"))
n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Populate").Columns("B:B"))

ReDim PaymentTerms(j - 1) As String
ReDim PaymentFreq(n - 1) As String
ReDim PaymentTermsAlt(j - 1) As String

For i = 1 To j - 1
    PaymentTerms(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Range("A2:A" & (j - 1)).Cells(i, 1)
    UserForm1.ComboTerms.AddItem PaymentTerms(i)
Next i

For m = 1 To n - 1
    PaymentFreq(m) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Range("B2:B" & (n - 1)).Cells(m, 1)
    UserForm1.ComboFreq.AddItem PaymentFreq(m)
Next m

For o = 1 To j - 1
    PaymentTermsAlt(o) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Range("A2:A" & (j - 1)).Cells(o, 1)
    UserForm1.ComboTermsAlt.AddItem PaymentTermsAlt(o)
Next o

UserForm1.ComboTerms.Text = PaymentTerms(1)
UserForm1.ComboFreq.Text = PaymentFreq(1)
UserForm1.ComboTermsAlt.Text = PaymentTermsAlt(1)

End Sub

Sub RunForm()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Activate
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Inside Userform:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Not IsNumeric(BasePay) Or Not IsNumeric(Interest) Then
MsgBox ("Please Enter Numeric Value for Base Pay or Interest Rate")
Exit Sub
End If

If BasePay < 0 Or Interest < 0 Then
MsgBox ("Base Pay or Interest cannot be negative value")
Exit Sub
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("A1") = "Prepared For " & ClientName
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("O1").Value = BasePay.Text
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("S2").Value = Interest.Text / 100
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("L3").Value = ComboTerms.Text
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("O3").Value = ComboFreq.Text
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("Q2").Value = ComboTermsAlt.Text

If NewCar Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("U2").Value = "New"
Else
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("U2").Value = "Used"
End If


'----- Transfer Add-On Items to Printout Sheet ---------
Dim i           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer
Dim k           As Integer

k = 6
For i = 1 To 9
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Cells(k, 1).MergeArea.ClearContents
    k = k + 2
Next

k = 6
For i = 10 To 18
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Cells(k, 5).MergeArea.ClearContents
   k = k + 2
Next

k = 6
For i = 19 To 27
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Cells(k, 9).MergeArea.ClearContents
    k = k + 2
Next

k = 6
For i = 28 To 36
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Cells(k, 13).MergeArea.ClearContents
    k = k + 2
Next

'---- Category 1 ------
i = 6
For j = 1 To 9
    If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("A" & i).Value = Me.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption
        i = i + 2
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("A" & i).Value = ""
    End If
Next j

'---- Category 2 ------
i = 6
For j = 10 To 18
    If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("E" & i).Value = Me.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption
        i = i + 2
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("E" & i).Value = ""
    End If
Next j

'---- Category 3 ------
i = 6
For j = 19 To 27
    If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("I" & i).Value = Me.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption
        i = i + 2
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("I" & i).Value = ""
    End If
Next j

'---- Category 4 ------
i = 6
For j = 28 To 36
    If UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Value = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("M" & i).Value = Me.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption
        i = i + 2
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Range("M" & i).Value = ""
    End If
Next j

UserForm1.Hide

End Sub

Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Sub NewCar_Click()


Dim LastRow     As Integer
Dim i           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Populate").Columns("D:D"))

'---- Count No of Checkbox
Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim n As Integer
Dim cbcount As Long

For n = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(UserForm1.Controls(n).Name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
        cbcount = cbcount + 1
    End If
Next n

i = 2 '--- Preset counter i
For j = 1 To cbcount
    UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Cells(i, 4).Value
    i = i + 1
    
    If i > LastRow And i < (cbcount / 4) Then
        UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption = ""
    End If
    
    If i > LastRow And i > (cbcount / 4 + 1) Then
        i = 2
    End If
        
Next j

End Sub

Sub UsedCar_Click()

Dim LastRow     As Integer
Dim i           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Populate").Columns("D:D"))

'---- Count No of Checkbox
Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim n As Integer
Dim cbcount As Long

For n = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(Me.Controls(n).Name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
        cbcount = cbcount + 1
    End If
Next n

i = 2 '--- Preset counter i
For j = 1 To cbcount
    UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Cells(i, 8).Value
    i = i + 1
    
    If i > LastRow And i < (cbcount / 4) Then
        UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption = ""
    End If
    
    If i > LastRow And i > (cbcount / 4 + 1) Then
        i = 2
    End If
        
Next j

End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call PopulateComboBox

'----- Rename Frame Boxes Caption
Dim k As Integer, nc As Integer
nc = 1
For k = 2 To 5
    Me.Controls("Frame" & k).Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Printout").Cells(5, nc)
    nc = nc + 4
Next k
'--------------------------------------------------


Dim LastRow     As Integer
Dim i           As Integer
Dim j           As Integer

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Columns("D:D"))

'---- Count No of Checkbox
Dim Ctrl As MSForms.Control
Dim n As Integer
Dim cbcount As Long

For n = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(Me.Controls(n).Name, 8) = "CheckBox" Then
        cbcount = cbcount + 1
    End If
Next n

i = 2 '--- Preset counter i
For j = 1 To cbcount
    UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Populate").Cells(i, 4).Value
    i = i + 1
    
    If i > LastRow And i < (cbcount / 4) Then
        UserForm1.Controls("Checkbox" & j).Caption = ""
    End If
    
    If i > LastRow And i > (cbcount / 4 + 1) Then
        i = 2
    End If
        
Next j
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The error is likely inside the UserForm code, so ask your user to set their VBA error handling to "break in class module" - it will be easier to see where the exact problem is.  Do you see that same problem if you send it to your self via email?

Comment: Hi Tim, 

I retried again and I found the problem is at the first two lines after dimming in Module1

`j = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Populate").Columns("A:A"))
n = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Populate").Columns("B:B"))`

I added `ThisWorkbook` in front of the sheets and it seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and advice though.

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.